# Prove by induction that $4^n≥n^4$ for all $n≥4$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Our teacher wrote the answer as follows
$$\begin{align}
4^{n+1}&=4\cdot 4^n\\
&≥4\cdot n^4\\
&≥4n^4\\
&≥n^4\\
&≥n^4 + 3n^4\\
&≥n^4 + 15n^3\\
&≥n^4 + 4n^3 + 6n^2 + 4n + 1\\
&=(n+1)^4
\end{align}$$
However, my class and I are not sure how he came to this conclusion.

Comment: The first step of the induction process is missing. A starting value of $n$

Answer (score 1):

Remark that, for $n=0 \ $ is true:

$$ 1=4^{0}\geq 0^{4} $$

for $n=1 \ $ is false

$$ 4^{1} < 1^{4}$$

for $n=2 \ $   is true:

$$ 16=4^{2} \geq 2^{4}=16 $$

for $n=3 \ $   is not true:

$$ 64=4^{3}<3^{4}=81 $$

Let $n\geq 4$, then when $n=4$, you just have $4^{4}\geq 4^{4}$. When $n>4$ you can use induction on $n$ by saying that $n=4$ is your starting value and you do:

**First by the induction hypothesis we have $4^{n}\geq n^{4}$ for all $n\geq 4$** and this implies the following:

$$4^{n+1}=4\cdot 4^{n}\geq 4\cdot n^{4} = n^{4}+3n^{4}$$

Assume $n\geq 5$, then you can multiply side by side by 3 and get:

$$ 3n\geq 15 $$

as $n\geq 5$ you can multiply both sides by $n^{3}$ to have:

$$ 3n^{4}\geq 15n^{3}$$

add to both sides $n^{4}$ to get:

$$ n^{4}+3n^{4}\geq n^{4}+15n^{3} $$

Finally, you have to show that $$ 15n^3 \geq 4n^3 + 6n^2 + 4n + 1 $$ which is true because:

$$ 15n^{3} = 4n^{3}+6n^{3}+4n^{3}+n^{3}$$ and the fact that $n\geq 5\geq 1$ give us:

$$ 4n^{3} \geq 4n^{3} $$

$$ 6n^{3} \geq 6n^{2} $$

$$ 4n^{3} \geq 4n$$

$$ n^{3}\geq 1 $$

because $n\geq 5$.

You can now add all these last inequalities together to get:

$$  15n^{3} \geq  4n^3 + 6n^2 + 4n + 1 $$

add to both sides $n^{4}$ to get:

$$ n^{4} + 15n^{3} \geq  n^{4}+4n^3 + 6n^2 + 4n + 1 =(n+1)^{4}$$

and we already show that $$ 4^{n+1} \geq n^{4}+3n^{4}\geq n^{4} + 15n^{3} $$

**You can assume $n\geq 5$ because for $n=4$ is direct the result. You can peak $n=5$ as starting value for induction.**

Comment: How did you get from: add to both sides $n^{4}$ to get:

$$ n^{4}+3n^{4}\geq n^{4}+15n^{3} $$

Finally, you have to show that $$ 15n^3 \geq 4n^3 + 6n^2 + 4n + 1 $$

Comment: @Ashivs: You just say, since 15n^3≥4n^3+6n^2+4n+1, then  n^4+15n^3≥n^4+4n3+6n2+4n+1=(n+1)^4

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have some errors in what you've written.  I'll try to correct the proof and provide details while keeping the same proof outline.  Sections underlined are corrections or are things that are missing from your original post.

*Step 1: State the claim*

We wish to prove that $4^n\geq n^4$ $\underline{\textbf{for all}~n\geq 4}$

$\underline{\textit{Step 2: Base case}}$

We check that it is in fact true for the smallest intended value of $n$, in this case $n=4$.  We see that indeed when $n=4$ we have $4^n\geq n^4$ as both sides are equal to $4^4$.

As a special case for this specific proof, we find it easier to also prove a second base case to make the induction step more convenient.  We see that indeed when $n=5$ we have $1024=4^5\geq 5^4=625$ is true.

*Step 3: Induction step*

We state again our induction hypothesis.  We assume that for some value of $k\geq 4$ that $4^k\geq k^4$ is true.  We wish to show that this being true for some value of $k$ will further imply that the claim will be true for $k+1$ as well, i.e. that $4^{k+1}\geq (k+1)^4$

We have:

$\require{cancel}\begin{array}{rlr}
4^{k+1}&=4\cdot 4^k&\text{properties of exponents}\\
\hline&\geq 4k^4&\text{by induction hypothesis}\\
\hline&\color{red}{\cancel{≥ n^4}}&\text{erroneous, removed}\\
\hline&\geq k^4 + 3k^4&\text{equal to previous line}\\
\hline&=\underline{k^4+3k\cdot k^3}&\text{properties of exponents}\\
\hline&\geq k^4 + 15k^3&\text{as}~k\geq 5~~(\dagger)\\
\hline&\underline{\geq k^4 + 4k^3+6k^3+4k^3+k^3}&\text{equal to previous line}\\
\hline&\geq k^4 + 4k^3 + 6k^2 + 4k + 1&\text{as}~k\geq 1\\
\hline&= (k + 1 )^4&\text{by binomial theorem}\end{array}$

Note, in the step marked with a $(\dagger)$ this was only true for values of $k\geq 5$ and is not true for $k=4$.  The step follows from the fact that since $k\geq 5$ we have $3k\geq 15$.  This is the reason why in this case we found it easier to use an additional base case.

Comment: beautiful writing, very clear.